# Work around lesser privileges

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I run this code:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE; 

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GreaterCircleNm;
DELIMITER go
CREATE FUNCTION GreaterCircleNm( lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
  DECLARE pi, q1, dist FLOAT;
  SET pi = PI();
  SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;
  SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;
  SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;
  SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;
SET q1 = ACOS(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon1-lon2));
SET dist = q1*180*60/pi;
RETURN dist;
END;
go
DELIMITER ;
```

I get an error telling me I don't have super privileges. My hosting provider already told me that it is not possible for me to (1) get those privileges or (2) have them run the code. That leaves me with option (3) which is to remove `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;` while still creating the function. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @GolezTrol Have I tried what? Running that code? Yes. Removing the SET GLOBAL portion? Yes.

Comment: @GolezTrol You aren't making any sense. If you mean did doing those two things work, then you obviously didn't read the whole thing because I said that it didn't work. Why would I even post this if it did?

Answer (score 1):

You can't `SET GLOBAL` anything without SUPER privilege.
Cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html

> The SUPER privilege is required to set global variables.

You can't `SET SESSION` for this variable:

```
mysql> SET SESSION log_bin_trust_function_creators=0;
ERROR 1229 (HY000): Variable 'log_bin_trust_function_creators' 
is a GLOBAL variable and should be set with SET GLOBAL
```

This is confirmed by the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) which lists the variable as GLOBAL only, not SESSION based.

So no, you can't work around this.  You'll have to ask your provider to create the function for you if they don't want to give you SUPER privilege.

Or else get a different hosting plan from another provider that allows you SUPER privilege.

Or else don't do this calculation in an SQL stored function.

Comment: "Or else don't do this calculation in an SQL stored function." - This probably should be first; a simple calculation like this should almost always be run in the client-side, not on the database directly.

Comment: @KKobayashi, that's one option, but I didn't necessarily mean that the only other choice is to do it client-side.  One could do the calculation by full expression in either the select-list or the where clause of an SQL query.  The result of the calculation may be used as conditions for row restriction.